# Trato de cambiar el valor html a una <td> y no lo hace

Tags: jquery

Buen dia, estoy tratando de cambiar el valor de un 'td' que al inicio tiene "-" al presentar la tabla, pero conforme se va digitando el codigo del producto ejecuta AJAX y si encuentra el codigo del producto, coloca la descripcion del mismo.
La respuesta del AJAX es correcta, lo que pasa es que no me deja cambiar el contenido del , lo raro es que si lo ejecuto en mi computadora, en mi localhost si funciona, pero en el servidor hosting NO.
Este es el codigo que uso para hacer el reemplazo.

```
                $('#txt_descripcion').html(info.descrip);
```

[image: en el primer textbox se digita el codigo del producto y deberia ir mostrando la descripcion, conforme se vaya encontrando el codigo.]

Comment: Se me olvidaba comentar el id y el name del TD es txt_descripcion

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a SO en español. No hace falta que coloques comentarios. Puedes editar la pregunta y añadir lo necesario. Trata de colocar siempre la mayor cantidad de tedxto posible, por ejemplo, código HTML que tengas de ejemplo, CSS que tengas de ejemplo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes asegurarte de estar usando una versión superior a la 1.0
Segundo comprobar que se encuentre tu objeto html y no agregue algo mas tu editor por ejemplo en ASP.NET con Visual Studio cuando agregas un botón por default agrega algo así como "ContentControls_txtDescripcion", entonces en tu versión de producción comprueba que así se llame tu elemento.
Tercero como solución trata de ocupar vainilla JS(JavaScript puro), porque algunos navegadores no soportan todas las funciones de JQUERY.
y por ultimo podrías intentar algo así:

crear el objeto jQuery en una variable y posteriormente añadir la función .html() a ese objeto.

```
$('td#txt_descripcion').html(info.descrip);
```

Suerte

Comment: Gracias José, he hecho algunos cambios de acuerdo a tu consejo pero sigo sin resolver, te comento que lo raro es que mi localhost si funciona la aplicacion web, es al correrla desde el hosting que no funciona.